# When calling JPA's remove() : "A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()"

Tags: jpa, persistence

I created a `Role` entity, I would like to do CRUD operations on it. Everything works well, except the "D" (delete) operation.

I use something similar to this [ObjectDB example code](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete#Explicit_Remove_).

As stated in the WebPage quoted above,

> An IllegalArgumentException is thrown
>   by remove if the argument is not a an
>   instance of an entity class or if it
>   is a detached entity.

How should I do that? What did I do wrong?

My `Role` entity is related to a `User` entity (a role can "have" several users, a user only one role). However, the `Role` instance I want to remove is by no means linked to any active user instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for your answer, but it did not help me much. Though I do think it was related to JTA. 
I found out a solution however, so I 'd like to share it here :

Instead of :

```
public void removeRole(Role aRole) {
    entityManager.remove(aRole);    
}
```

All I had to do was :

```
public void removeRole(Role aRole) {
entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(aRole));   
}
```

And that does the trick.  Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting?

If you are using JTA, you cannot use EntityManager transactions, you must use JTA transactions (EJB, or lookup user transaction from conext).  Either don't configure JPA to use JTA, or use JTA not EM transactions.

Answer (score 0):

```
userTransaction.begin();
                    
entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(entity))

userTransaction.commit();
```

this one will work.